# Give out a NSMutableArray on a texView on another Viewcontroller in objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I try to save numbers from a textfield on one viewController in a NSMutableArray when I press a button on this viewContoller. (this is working now)
Then i want the numbers give out on a textview which is on a secondViewController but this dont work. When i want to give out the array on the first Viewcontroller it work fine.
Also i cant erase the NSMutableArray with a button on the SecondviewController.

The SecondviewController have the same class like the viewController.

Can someone show me how i can give out an array on a seconviewcontroller?

Hallo,
at the moment i have this:

//ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
NSMutableArray *textViewArray;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textLable2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textLable1;

- (IBAction)setArrayWithCurrentNumber:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)returnToTextfield:(id)sender;

@end
```

//this the .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize textLable2;
@synthesize textLable1;


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    textViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTextLable2:nil];
    [self setTextLable1:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)setArrayWithCurrentNumber:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *string1 = self.textLable1.text;
    [textViewArray addObject:string1];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:textViewArray];
    NSString *string2 = [array componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

    self.textLable2.text = [NSString stringWithString:string2];
    NSLog(@"%@",textViewArray);
}

- (IBAction)returnToTextfield:(id)sender 
{
    [textLable1 resignFirstResponder];
    [textLable2 resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling the second view controller from the first one you could set a property on the second one to hold the NSMutableArray or just send it on the initializer.

something like:

```
- (id)initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        myArray = [array copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

assuming your second view controller has declared NSMutableArray * myArray;

Edit: Adding some more code in here...

```
// I'll assume you use some kind of UINavigationController to show your content
- (void)showSecondViewController {
    SecondViewController * vc = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithArray:yourMutableArray] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc];
}
```

Comment: How cn i send it on the initializer?

Comment: I've added the second vc initialization.